# How to load existing Jquery object to webpack module in ProvidePlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, build-tools

I'm using webpack in my project as build tool and in-order to have jquery reference i've configured jquery in plugin as below.

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "window.jQuery":"jquery"
    })
  ]
```

But my existing project i've added some user-defined function to Jquery object as below.

```
 $.fn.hasScrollBar = function() { //code goes here}
```

So, How will i get this function in webpack bundle when configuring Jquery in ProvidePlugin?

Comment: Maybe the files are being bundled in the wrong order.

Comment: Is the order of your pack correct? Sounds like your script was placed before jQuery or after the call ...

Comment: It placed after the Jquery